# Linq to XML spotify parsing

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to read the following xml file from spotify: http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=sail+awolnation

I want to get all the tracks in a collection, I've been trying to use Linq to XML but no success so far, all the examples I found do it the exact same way as I do, but for some reason it does not populate the list for me and I'm left clueless.

Here is my code I am using at the moment:

```
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.spotify.com/ns/music/1");

        var tracks =  from track in xdoc.Descendants(ns + "track")
                    select new
                    {
                        Name = track.Element(ns + "name").Value,
                    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebClient wb = new WebClient();
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(wb.DownloadString("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=sail+awolnation"));
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.spotify.com/ns/music/1");
var tracks = from track in xdoc.Root.Elements(ns + "track") 
     select 
       new 
        { 
           Name = track.Element(ns + "name").Value 
        };
string s = "";
```

this code is working fine with me

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having an issue with the Namespace.

I'd personally go about getting the Namespace like this

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=sail+awolnation");
XNamespace ns = xDoc.Document.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
```

This ensures that if the Namespace ever does change (by Spotify) then your program will automatically handle it and you wont have to change code and recompile to make it work with the new one.